# How to sync maps in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I want to sync two maps in an R shiny web app(zooming in on one map should zoom in on the other map and panning etc), I managed to do this interactively using the code shown below but I can't figure out how to do this in a Shiny web app. Any help would be appreciated

```
my_map <- function(x){
    m <- leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
    addMarkers(lng=x[1], lat=x[2], popup="The birthplace of R")
    m
}

y <- c(174.968, 37.852)
x <- c(0.112281, 51.523001)

sync(my_map(x), my_map(y), no.initial.sync = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will the maps always be made prior to user interface creation? If so:

```
library(leaflet)
library(leafsync)
library(shiny)

my_map <- function(x){
  m <- leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
    addMarkers(lng=x[1], lat=x[2], popup="The birthplace of R")
  m
}

y <- c(174.968, 37.852)
x <- c(0.112281, 51.523001)

ui <- sync(my_map(x), my_map(y), no.initial.sync = TRUE)

server = function(input,output){
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Edit:**

In response to your comment, I have looked at options to sync maps including a javascript approach (https://github.com/jieter/Leaflet.Sync) and syncWith (https://github.com/rte-antares-rpackage/leaflet.minicharts). I have not spent time with these.

A quick workaround could be this below (one map's bounds matches the other map's bounds, but not vice versa). It requires adding observe to the server function and setting the bounds from one map to the other. From http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html:

> input$MAPID_bounds provides the latitude/longitude bounds of the
>   currently visible map area; the value is a list() that has named
>   elements north, east, south, and west

```
library(leaflet)
library(leafsync)
library(shiny)

my_map <- function(x){
  m <- leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
    addMarkers(lng=x[1], lat=x[2], popup="The birthplace of R")
  m
}

y <- c(174.968, 37.852)
x <- c(0.112281, 51.523001)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap1"),
  leafletOutput("mymap2")
)

server = function(input, output){

  output$mymap1 = renderLeaflet({
    my_map(x)
  })
  output$mymap2 = renderLeaflet({
    my_map(y)
  })

  observe({
    coords <- input$mymap1_bounds
    if (!is.null(coords)) {
      leafletProxy("mymap2") %>% 
        fitBounds(coords$west,
                  coords$south,
                  coords$east,
                  coords$north)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi thank you this works for me. But my question is how do I create the map objects in UI (leafletOutput("hello")) and then render it in the server whilst still syncing?

Comment: @theBean see edits above - i included a potential work around after looking for other solutions...i wish i had something better to offer...

Answer (score 6):

Using `sync()` as an UI output, not as `leafletOutput` worked for me.

In `ui`:

```
uiOutput("synced_maps")
```

In `server`:

```
output$synced_maps <- renderUI({
   m1 <- leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers(~lon1, ~lat1)
   m2 <- leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers(~lon2, ~lat2)
   sync(m1, m2)      
})
```

Comment: Nicely done! I couldn't find this in any documentation. 
Is there a way to modify your solution to also work with leafletProxy?